# Why does unicode in a file name cause 'find' to add input to the terminal?

Tags: command-line, find

So I have the following file with a strange unicode name.  When I do a `find` command on the file it will print input to the terminal.  Look for the `62;c` at the bottom of the output.  Why does this happen?  Is it a bug or intentional?  I also got some similar output when I tried tab completion with the file name.

```
jeff@laptop:/tmp/x$ ls
057. Antonâ??â? n Dvoâ??Ã´â??Â°k - Rusalka - MÆ?Ãµsâ??â? Æ?Ã§ku Na Nebi Hlubokâ??Â©m.mp3
jeff@laptop:/tmp/x$ find
.
./057. Antonâ??â? n Dvoâ??Ã´â??Â°k - Rusalka - MÆ?Ãµsâ??â? Æ?Ã§ku Na Nebi Hlubokâ??Â©m.mp3�Â©m.mp3
jeff@laptop:/tmp/x$ 62;c
```

ls -ab shows the following:

```
057.\ Antonâ\302\210\302\232â\302\211 n\ Dvoâ\302\211\302\210Ã´â\302\210\302\232Â°k\ -\ Rusalka\ -\ MÆ\302\222Ãµsâ\302\210\302\232â\302\211 Æ\302\222Ã§ku\ Na\ Nebi\ Hlubokâ\302\210\302\232Â©m.mp3
```

One other piece of information.  I see the text in a 'terminal', but not in an 'xterm'.

Comment: What does `ls -ab` report?

Comment: https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php tells me that contains a bunch of [U+88/U+9A characters](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Control_characters#C1_set) which probably messes up the output.

Comment: How did the file appear here? From where and how was it copied?

Answer (score 2):

Certain escape sequences query the terminal (or terminal emulator) for certain parameters (such as version, features, current state). These, by design, can only answer by sending the response as an escape sequence *as if it was typed by the user*.

To try it out, execute e.g.

```
 echo -ne '\e[c'; sleep 100
```

and see `^[[?62;c` (i.e. an `ESC` followed by literal `[?62;c`) appearing, and backspace erasing it while `sleep` is running, exactly *as if you typed* this.

An alternate form of this particular escape sequence, using the C1 control code rather than the default C0, which is only supported by *some* terminal emulators if used in UTF-8, is:

```
echo -ne '\xC2\x9Bc'; sleep 100
```

(See the beginning of [ctlseqs.html](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) why xterm does not support these.)

Any application emitting such an escape is expected to wait for the response and act on it accordingly. Otherwise they should be careful enough not to produce such output.

For me (Ubuntu 18.04), `find` recognizes both of these and replaces them with question marks, to make sure they are not sent as-is to the terminal. You might be using an older version of `find` in an older Ubuntu, which did not yet properly filter these out, or you might be encountering a different escape sequence which is not filtered out (in this latter case we should file a bugreport against `findutils`). We'd need to know the *exact* filename (*exact* sequence of bytes) to continue investigating.

UPDATE: I've just discovered and filed a relevant bug: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?54236. Not sure if you're hitting this one.

Comment: find --version returns:  find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git

Comment: @Jeff Try `apt-cache policy findutils` instead

Comment: findutils:
  Installed: 4.6.0+git+20160126-2
  Candidate: 4.6.0+git+20160126-2
  Version table:
 *** 4.6.0+git+20160126-2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status